# How to use environment variable in log4cpp property file

Tags: c++, logging, environment-variables, cross-platform, log4cpp

I am using **log4cpp** for my C++ project. What I need is to generate log files in custom locations instead of current directory. For that, I have set some environment variables for log file path. The problem is how can I use this **environment variables** in log4cpp property file so that the log files are generated in that locations.

I tried various options like $(ENV_VAR), ${ENV_VAR}, %ENV_VAR% but none are working.

Thanks,
Hemant

Comment: a line like `log4cpp.appender.logfile.fileName=${TEMP}\MyProgram.log` used to work with `log4cpp` for me on Windows

Answer (score 1):

use ${sys:ENV_VAR} instead of ${ENV_VAR}

reference http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html

Comment: using ${ENV_VAR} on Linux worked. But on Windows, it is not working.